# Addition of an organization to existing network without using CLI container

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hi I have been following the [tutorials in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKuGU5CYV_E&t=159s) it uses CLI container to add an org. Since using CLI container is not recommended to have in production environment how to add an org into the existing network withput using cli container

Answer (score 0):

the following tutorial from the IBM developer works, should help you further for the moment:

[IBM Developer works description of configtxlator tool](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-add-an-organization-to-your-hyperledger-fabric-blockchain/index.html)

At short:

> 1. extract current config from genesis block
> 2. Convert to human readable format
> 3. Modify and do your changes
> 4. Convert back to binary format
> 5. Apply changes to the network

The tool is available in the `cli` container or can be found here in the sources of the current master:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/common/tools/configtxlator

And further, more complete samples are available here.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/configtxupdate

Answer (score 0):

Everything a CLI container can do can be done without a container. You need the peer or orderer binaries (configtx and configtxlator for network modifications) and access to the MSP crypto and a correct core.yaml and/or orderer.yaml. That's what's in the CLI containers now. For development I just use the existing peers and/or orderers, since they already have all of that.